# Linux/C: Redirecting Pipes to STDIN/STDOUT

Tags: c, linux, pipe, dup2

I was having trouble with simulating the shell script "env | grep HOME" with a C program. I found that commenting out line 29 solved this problem, but I'm not really sure why! I read on another question that it was because dup2() was closing the fd in the child, but the man page doesn't indicate that. Can anyone give me a definitive reason and help me understand this behavior? Thank you!

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main(void){
 pid_t childpid;
 int fd[2];
 if(pipe(fd) == -1){ /*setup a pipe*/
  perror("Failed to setup pipeline");
  return 1;
 }
 if((childpid = fork()) == -1){ /*fork a child*/
  perror("Failed to fork a child");
  return 1;
 }
 if(childpid == 0){ /*env is the child*/
  if(dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO)==-1)
   perror("Failed to redirect stdout of env");
  else if(close(fd[0] == -1)) /*close unused file descriptor*/
   perror("Failed to close extra pipe descriptors on env");
  else{
   execl("/usr/bin/env", "env", NULL); /*execute env*/
   perror("Failed to exec env");
  }
  return 1;
 }
 if(dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO)==-1) /*grep is the parent*/
  perror("Failed to redirect stdin of grep");
 //else if(close(fd[1]==-1))
  //perror("Failed to close extra pipe file descriptors on grep");
 else{
  execl("/bin/grep", "grep", "HOME", NULL); /*execute "grep HOME"*/
  perror("Failed to exec grep");
 }
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? If it's just hanging, it's because you're not closing all your file descriptors. (You leak a ton of file descriptors aside from stdin/stdout/stderr into the both `execl` calls.) In both children, make sure you close the other end of the file descriptor. (You mostly do this; one is commented out.) You also need to close the file descriptor after you `dup2` it to the right FD: no reason to keep it open, and `env` won't close it until it dies. (Edit: Ah, and the misplaced `)` as Sean Pedersen shows.)

Comment: The current (typo) error aside, you are doing this wrong.  What you really want are two children, one executing `env` and piping the output to the other one executing ` grep`.As is the parent is execing `grep`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason outside the fact that you normally want to keep the parent alive instead of execing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your bug. Here's what exits properly for me. It's a common mistake:

```
...
        else if (close(fd[0]) == -1) /*close unused file descriptor*/
            ...
    else if(close(fd[1]) == -1)
    ...
```

What you were doing originally was setting the file descriptor to be closed to the boolean value of `fd[x] == -1`, and what you wanted to do was check for `-1` in the return value of `close()`.

Comment: I was hoping you'd actually describe the mistake, since it's a single character error. Visually comparing your answer and the OP's post might not help, since he's already overlooking this.

Comment: That was it! Man, can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you.