# Execution of a file with a redirection of the buffers using execl()

Tags: c, linux, exec, io-redirection

I'm using linux and c (eclipse and gcc) to program.

I wish to run a program from a child process and kill if it won't finish after a certain time.
The program is a command line program which receives data from the keyboard and transmits a string to the screen.

I use to use the

```
system("/path/file_name <input.txt >outoput.txt")
```

command but since I wish to kill it after some time and system() opens a new PID I switched to `execl()`.

The command I use is:

```
execl("/path/file_name" , "/path/file_name" , "<input.txt" , ">outoput.txt" , (char *) NULL);
```

It works as far as loading my program but the keyboard is still the input buffer and I get all the data to the screen.

I changed it into:

```
execl("/path/file_name" , "/path/file_name<input.txt>outoput.txt" , (char *) NULL);
```

and I still get the same thing - any ideas?

I don't know how to use pipes so unless if you have a code to share with me such an advice won't help me.

Comment: Maybe you should learn about pipes?

Comment: Where do you want it to get input from and send output to, if not the keyboard and screen?

Comment: I have a text file that contains the data for input and i want to send the screen into a text file

Comment: This question's approach might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22432578/694576